# Let $A_j, j \in J$ be disjoint measurable subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ such that $m_n(A_j) >0$ for every $j \in J$. Show that $J$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A_j, j \in J$ be disjoint measurable subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ such that $m_n(A_j) >0$ for every $j \in J$. Show that $J$ is countable.

I've tried to come up with a contradiction, but I cannot figure out anything here. I suppose there is no easy direct way to show this so contradiction would be in place?

I only have that $m_n(\bigcup_{j \in J} A_j ) \le \sum_{j \in J} m_n(A_j)$, but this doesn't seem to help here. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

For $k\in\mathbb N$, let $$J_k:=\{j\in J:m_n(A_j\cap[-k,k]^n)>0\}.$$
Show that:

1. Each $J_k$ is countable.
2. We have $J=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}J_k$.

Comment: What's the motivation for this set $J_k$?

Comment: @UniQGat: reducing the problem to the case where the space has finite measure.